# JMeter encrypted credentials

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When I recorded the login process, the password is encrypted in the request, so when I tried to change the credentials by setting the password to plain text, I get 500 response code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to identify the encoding mechanism and encrypt the password on the fly using [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) the following example encodes value stored under `${plainpassword}` variable using [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding and stores encrypted value as `${encodedpassword}` variable

```
import org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64;

String plainPassword = vars.get("plainpassword");
String encodedPassword = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainPassword.getBytes()));
vars.put("encodedpassword", encodedPassword);
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter and a form of Beanshell cookbook.